# Get chat window fixed to bottom

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a project for which I'm making a chat right now. 
Everything chat related is working just fine, but my problem is that I want the chat window to be fixed to the bottom when overflow-y is active so I don't have to manually scroll down to see the latest messages. (Something how Facebook chat & twitch.tv chat works)

(I'm sorry that I cannot show any of my attempts in doing this as I just don't know what to do.)

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here is some of the HTML & CSS Code.

Note: Actual messages are pushed as strings to logs

//CSS

```
#chat {
  margin-top: 110px;
  background-color: #FAF9FA;
  height: 75%;
}

#chat-window {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

//HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div id="chat">
        <div id="chat-window">
            <div id="logs">

            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="spec" id="message" placeholder="Type your message..."/></br>
        <button id="send" class="btn">Send</button>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try position: fixed in the style attribute or class css?

Comment: @GurpreetSingh Yes, but that doesn't really help, it really just breaks everything.

Comment: Then perhaps you should try fixing the broken parts rather that finding a bad solution. position: fixed is in general the proper way to go. Also, it's independent of overflow or scroll in any of it's child.

Answer (score 2):

Well if your goal is to simply scroll to the bottom:

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.getElementById('myChatWindow').scrollHeight);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if i catch your goal, but i think that just css position:fixed solve your problem.

```
.chat-box {
   position: fixed;
   background: #ccc;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   padding: 20px;
}
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/Julivan/261qjdp9/

hope it helps